# p:treenode getParent convert to object

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to create a tree as follow

```
    TreeNode root= new DefaultTreeNode("Root",null);
    Factory factory= new Factory();
    TreeNode tempTreeNode = new DefaultTreeNode(factory,root);
    Car car = new Car();
    TreeNode tempTreeNode1 = new DefaultTreeNode(car,tempTreeNode);
```

I would like to get the parent of a node, so I try to get its parent

```
    public String findParentId(TreeNode selectedTreeNode){
    TreeNode parent = selectedTreeNode.getParent();
    Factory tempFactory = (Factory)parent;
    return tempFactory.getId();
    }
```

org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode cannot be cast to ...(the object)

I would like to know how can I cast the treeNode to Object(Factory).

Comment: You just don't. Look at the api of TreeNode. Also check the PF showcase and documenation. It is all in there

Comment: @Kukeltje got it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong assumption. You should not cast the TreeNode to your own object but on the treenode to a `.getObject()` and cast **that** to your own object.

```
public String findParentId(TreeNode selectedTreeNode){
    TreeNode parent = selectedTreeNode.getParent();
    Factory tempFactory = (Factory)parent.getData();
    return tempFactory.getId();
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro. I used the following code to perform it.
(Factory)parent.getData()

Comment: Sorry, typo. Corrected.